# Can't find entity after saving it in the datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine

After calling put() i get the id 1952002

When I got to the datastore viewer, the entity is not there. When I query it for this entity, there is no results

```
public String addFeedback(String feedbackText) {
    Text TextFeedbackText = new Text(feedbackText);
    Entity entity = new Entity("FeedBack");
    entity.setProperty("feedbackText", TextFeedbackText);
    return "" + datastore.put(entity).getId(); // returns 1952002
}
```

This function used to work fine. I havn't used it for a while but now it stopped working.
I checked the logs, everything is fine

> 2014-03-18 19:40:00.856 /feedback/add/ 200 258ms 0kb module=default
>   version=2
>   151.228.xxx.xxx - - [18/Mar/2014:12:40:00 -0700] "POST /feedback/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 33 - - "xxxxx.appspot.com" ms=258 cpu_ms=42
>   cpm_usd=0.000004 app_engine_release=1.9.0
>   instance=00cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx19ec5

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: Does the id for the data you store only exist in the scope of the method or does it actually exist outside as well?

Comment: @Vipar Can you rephrase that please. I don't understand

Comment: If the datastore.put is a google api call, it is very likely that google has dropped support for the call or changed the api without informing you.

Comment: Your code is correct. If you see an id, the entity was saved to the Datastore. Do you see "FeedBack" in the list of entity kinds in the Viewer?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes i see Feedback. it is full of entities from a while ago, but not any new ones. I am using the same code i set the old ones with

Comment: Did you try "Flush Memcache"?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I just tried again, and now it started working again. I don't know why. it could be because I havnt stored anything in FeedBack for a while. or maybe google were having problems

Answer (score 1):

"It started working all by itself"

98% of the time people encounter this when storing an entity and then not seeing it when they do a query, it's due to 'eventual consistency'.

For a full explanation, and a way forward, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: Less formal (and fun to read) explanation of 'eventual consistency': https://plus.google.com/+YonatanZunger/posts/ZZ9wDbLDr3A

Answer (score 0):

It started working all by it self again.

It could be that google were having an issue or maybe it is due to the lack of usage of this particular table.